# Sitecore 8 Security Editor - Read vs Visibility

Tags: editor-user-permissions

In the Security Editor, I can set Read, Write, Delete, etc. permissions on an item.

Can someone tell me the difference between Read and Visibility permissions? What's the proper use of Visibility?

[image]

Sitecore 8.0 rev 150121

Comment: Looking in the Security Editor of a solution in Sitecore 8.1u2 I'm not seeing "visibility" anywhere, and I'm not familiar with it. Could you provide a screenshot and/or describe where I might find it? (Knowing me, it's probably staring me in the face, right now)

Comment: thanks @ZacharyKniebel. I added an image and noted my specific version - 8.0 rev 150121

Comment: Well, isn't that interesting! Where'd it go in 8.1? Hahaha I didn't see anything in the release notes about it between 7.0 initial and 8.1u2, and it doesn't exist in 7.2 (latest). I also just checked on 8.0.150812 and it wasn't there either.

Comment: It looks like some custom setting. I don't have this one in 8.1

Comment: Can you run ShowConfig.aspx and see if the custom "visibility" Access Right is defined under "accessRights/rights"? Maybe this was implemented from a genius John West blog post.

Comment: Generally ”visibility” is used, when you want to hide data from a user (tree navigation or search) but the application still need to read the data in order to function (say setting items or sensitive data repositories) – normally in Sitecore you could use the security.disabler for this, but I have seen this abstraction layer in other solutions.

Comment: @MichaelWest yes, that's it! I am new to this project and didn't realize that had been customized.

Comment: @JasonBooth any chance you can share through here or a blogpost as to the implementation of the Access Rule? May prove very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @michaelwest in the comments, this turned out to be a custom access right added to our solution. I need to dig into how we are using it but I think it is what @sandbeck is describing above - hiding an item from the user but allowing the application to still use it.

Thanks for the comments!